# What factors affect how fast HTML5 videos will start playing?

Tags: html5, video, video-hosting

If I host videos on my server and include them as HTML5 video in a webpage, what factors affect how fast they will start playing?

Of course **bandwidth** is a factor, but does also the media type of the video (MP4, WebM Ogg) affect this?

Any other factors to consider?

Comment: Just a word of warning: that's a great way to take down your website.

Comment: @TimGrant, could you elaborate on that? It's a couple of small thumbnail videos in a catalog.

Comment: If the videos cause any unexpected slowdown of the site, you can end up with people hitting reload, further increasing the number of videos that get requested. I once watched 9 web servers fall like dominoes when this happened. It doesn't mean it will happen to you, just proceed with caution.

Answer (score 2):

These are the key factors that should be considered with regards to video regardless of BW.

You should post 3 formats when possible, to serve the proper device used.

- mp4, webm, ogg

This not only saves you bandwidth but also the users who do not need large video files for clarity.

Next you should encode the video file into a **h264 format wrapped in a mp4 container**.

Also use **variable bitrates**. This drops the mbps when there are dark scenes or low action.

The same applies for the audio, when the music is not as active.
Lastly use a **fast start streaming** which is also known as **web streaming** depending what OS and APP you use.

And a good program to go with would be **FFMPEG/X** or **Handbrake**

[image]